# How to write JSON efficiently to a file while maintaining referential transparency?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

My main objective is to write JSON lines to a file efficiently while maintaining referential transparency. I have two main questions:

1. Is writing to the file line by line efficient? Or is there a better way where I can buffer the json and write it in batches (I am assuming that is faster than writing line by line)
2. How can I maintain referential transparency while writing to the file? (to my understanding I need to wrap part of the code in an IO Monad, but I am not sure what is the correct way to do this or how to run it safely). Further readings are welcome.

I have created some sample code to show what I have reached so far in my code (only a snippet):

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._, io.circe.syntax._

for (u <- someList) println(u.asJson.noSpaces)
// resulting Json (sample):
// {"id":"1","name":"Mr Foo","roles":["Chief Foo Officer"],"phone_number":null}
// {"id":"2","name":"Mr Bar","roles":["Chief Bar Officer"],"phone_number":null}
// .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list is big you can use a **Stream** like this:

```
import cats.effect.{Blocker, ContextShift, IO, Sync}
import fs2.Stream
import io.circe.Encoder
import io.circe.syntax._
import java.nio.file.{Path, Paths}

def writeToFileAsJsons[A : Encoder, F[_] : Sync : ContextShift](data: List[A], path: Path, blocker: Blocker): F[Unit] =
  Stream
  .emits(data)
  .covary[F]
  .map(_.asJson.noSpaces)
  .through(fs2.text.utf8Encode)
  .through(fs2.io.file.writeAll(path, blocker))
  .compile
  .drain
```

And call the method like:

```
val program: IO[Unit] =
  Blocker[IO].use { blocker =>
    writeToFileAsJsons[Int, IO](
      data = List(1, 2, 3),
      path = Paths.get("foo", "bar.txt"),
      blocker
    )
  }
```

*(as long as there is a **ContextShift** for `IO` in scope)*

---

If the list is really big you may want to have a **Stream** from the beginning, and if it is not that big then do not worry too much about it.

Comment: Looking forward to try that one! Is there a simpler method (I have the feeling could be a big hammer for a small nail in some cases). Is there a simpler (naive) more that is more naive for that implementation?

Comment: @alt-f4 yeah as I said, if the list is small just do a foreach and print each element into the file using whatever API you like for writing to a file.